# How to send emails via G-suite from Google Cloud

Tags: email, go, google-cloud-platform, smtp, google-workspace

How can you send an email in Go from the Google Cloud owner G-suite email account?

Is it possible to use the Google Cloud projectID existing authorizations, without specifying the Google account password inside the Go source files?

Comment: Passwords should never be in source files. They should be in environment variables, or stored in files that you've told your repo to ignore.

Comment: I was wondering if on Google Cloud, you could completely avoid specifying a password for sending an email

Comment: Is this on App Engine? Standard, or Flex, or Compute Engine?

Comment: using Compute Engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found the solution!**

And it's very simple: instead of specifying the account password, you can restrict the connection to **your server IP address**.

1) Sign in to your Google Admin console (https://admin.google.com) using the G-suite administrator account

2) Click on **Apps** -> **G Suite** -> **Gmail** -> **Advanced settings**

3) At the bottom of the page, mouse over on **SMTP Relay Service** and click on "*ADD ANOTHER*"

4) As **Allowed Sender** select "*Only addresses in my domain*"

5) Check **Only accept mail from the specified IP addresses** and type *your server IP address*

6) Confirm by clicking on "*ADD SETTING*" and then "*SAVE*"

This is the Go code required to send an email:

```
from := "myuser@mydomain.com"
to := "mail@recipient.com"

msg := "From: " + from + "\n" +
    "To: " + to + "\n" +
    "Subject: Hello there\n\n" +
    "SOME TEXT"

err := smtp.SendMail("smtp-relay.gmail.com:587", nil,
    from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))

if err != nil {
    log.Printf("smtp error: %s", err)
}
```

Comment: you could also store the password information in secrets manager and pull it from there within your cloud application

Answer (score 1):

An even better way is to create API/OAuth2 credentials directly in Google Cloud.
In this way you don't even have to specify the server IP addresses as a security measure:

https://medium.com/wesionary-team/sending-emails-with-go-golang-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-185ee12ab306